# Can I get a PhD in Stochastic Analysis given this limited background?

Tags: soft-question, stochastic-calculus, education, economics, advice

General advice on PhD apps welcome

**Given my limited background in stochastic analysis and other information (below), can I apply for a PhD with stochastic analysis for my dissertation topic?**

1/4 I am currently a masteral student of mathematical finance, expecting to graduate sometime this year. I am not particularly interested in mathematical finance anymore unless it is in a rigorous context rather than with computers, modeling, statistics, non-mathematical finance, simulations, etc.

2/4 **I am taking up my second course in Stochastic Calculus along with other subjects. I have already taken up one course in StoCal and one course in probability with measure theory.**

Edit: Here are my other subjects in grad and undergrad that may be relevant:

(Duh: Calculus I, II, III, Linear Algebra, Elementary Probability), ODE, PDE, Statistics, Time Series, More Time Series, More Statistics (oh my!), Discrete Mathematics, Numerical Analysis, Real Analysis, NO Complex Analysis

One derivatives pricing course talked about martingales, measures, stochastic processes but those were taught heuristically there and rigorously in StoCal courses. So those 3 above are really my main background in Stochastic Analysis/Stochastic Calculus (whatever you call it) unless knowing its applications is helpful.

3/4 I don't know about calculus of variations, Malliavin Calculus, different kinds of convergence of random variables, laws of large numbers, etc. We were not even given the full proof of Ito's lemma in classes.

4/4 **My thesis is about credit risk**, having mainly to do with statistics, [the part of mathematical finance I don't want to go in to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_finance#History:_Q_versus_P), if I were still interested in mathematical finance. Hence, I feel have **no background in mathematical research** given that the research conducted was mainly to do with statistics and finance.

Given my limited background in stochastic analysis and probability theory, can I already apply for a PhD in stochastic analysis?

**If not, must I then take a master's in mathematics** to see if I might take on stochastic analysis for another thesis? I just want to be really sure of my dissertation topic before I apply (as is expected of PhD applicants, right?).

So perhaps another thing to ask is: **How do I know if I am ready to apply for a PhD (in terms of the dissertation topic and not the readiness for the level of studies)**?

Oh, more info:

1/2 I like to think I am very passionate about mathematics and am more interested studying stochastic calculus and probability more than my other classes. But never having done mathematical research, I don't know really if I am ready. I don't want to naively think what I have is enough.

2/2 I am not particularly interested in statistics, which is sort of related to probability. Hopefully, this isn't relevant...?

Comment: Have you tried contacting someone who works in the area directly? Surely you'll have to learn a lot of analysis, but your 'informal' background in the area will help you. If you start a phd in any subject, you'll have to learn a lot of background material anyways. If you really lack a lot of background, the phd may take longer to complete and that could be an issue.

Comment: @ChrisDugale Thanks. No, I'm not sure where precisely I plan to take a PhD, but it is in a certain country. Sorry, I forgot to include my undergraduate subjects. Adding now. Hope you can comment further on the update.

Comment: @ChrisDugale Done. My other concern is lack of mathematical research. Might that be a problem i.e. I am too naive to make a decision/I don't know what I'm getting into?...Also, does it really depend on the institution? I'd imagine most universities with stochastic calculus people would have a common idea about such a background...

Comment: Well I can't give you very specific advice as I do not work in the area. But the reason why it's a good idea to contact someone directly is because some may want you to be able to start learning about the subject right away, which might not be particularly easy if you don't have a strong background. Others may be okay with you taking the time. The fact that you have already seen some of the applications, and worked with them, is a significant advantage. I imagine most people encounter the subject in applied areas and then decide that they want to do a phd in it afterwards.

Comment: So your situation might not be that unusual. By applied, I mean they learned about the subject in a physics or financial program. People don't expect you to have a research program when you start your phd. And while you might not have any 'theoretical' research experience, you do have research experience that is directly relevent to the subject, which is huge.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDugale. "The fact that you have already seen some of the applications, and worked with them, is a significant advantage." How could I not realize that? Lol. I guess that derivatives pricing course is relevant after all. "you do have research experience that is directly relevent to the subject, which is huge. " Erm, no. :(( Please see 4. Sto Cal or Ito Cal is more relevant to the other side of mathematical finance. Do you think maybe my financial research is sufficient background for doing mathematical research?

Comment: Or do you know how I might know? (aside from applying or asking my professors, which I plan to do soon) "People don't expect you to have a research program when you start your phd." Aren't most phd programs expecting master's? Having nearly completed this degree, I cannot imagine some undergrad going to a phd but apparently straight phds are a thing. Research is tough, and I'm sure I don't know the half of it. Anyway, I guess in terms of work ethic (or what do you call it), I would be able to handle research. I am wondering if I could be able to handle mathematical/theoretical research.

Comment: @ChrisDugale I noted that this isn't your area, but it looks like you're into cryptography, but you seem to be well-versed in other people's experience? Thank you for sharing their experience ^_^

Comment: [*Please* don't cross-post.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38899/4140) Instead, flag your question for migration; a moderator will take care of this. [See here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/256777)

Comment: You need grades, letters of recommendation, and personal statement (standardized tests may also be a factor).  Your personal statement should be interesting and show that you have a general interest in stochastic analysis, and paint a picture of one avenue you could possibly explore, perhaps with a specific example. It does not matter if you end up doing that or something completely different. You have much more specific course background in stochastics and finance than most. Faculty may like that.

Comment: If you are applying to work in the area of theory it is good to have recs that say you were at the top of your math class and demonstrated depth.  If you did any mathematical work and/or publications it would be great, regardless of topic.  Faculty understand that smart people can do anything. Make sure to describe what the interesting aspect of your work was. Do not be boring.

Comment: You can email individual faculty to introduce your application.  List as many faculty as you can if the application gives you the chance.  Apply to a set of schools, not just one or two.

Comment: @Michael Thank you thank you thank you!